# Conditional selection on Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe (call it df):
[image]

Here's what I want to do with the dataframe:
1. Select the rows that match with Col1 and Col2, if there are two rows for each id.
2. If there's only one row for the id, then select the row, even if the Col1 and Col2 do not match.

```
df = df[df['Col1'] == df['Col2']]
```

This code is wrong, because it doesn't satisfy the requirement 2 above. This is the result I want:[image]

I would really appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to accomplish this!
Thank you.

Comment: please include the code that generates your dataframe

Comment: Columns 1 and 2 either match or don't. By requirement 1 and 2, won't we simply return the entire dataframe anyways?

Comment: dustin, the requirement 1: for the ids with two rows, want to select a row whose col1 and col2 match.
requirement 2: for the ideas with only one row, simply select that row.

Comment: @JunJang to me it isn't clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: d = {'id':['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '5', '5', '6', '6', '7'], 'Col1': ['Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Ramen', 'Ramen', 'Ramen', 'Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Ramen', 'Ramen', 'Pizza'], 'Col2': ['Pizza', 'Ramen', 'Ramen', 'Pizza', 'Ramen', 'Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Ramen', 'Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Ramen', 'Ramen'], 'Col3': [100, 30, 150, 300, 230, 20, 13, 230, 13, 35, 30, 45]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

Comment: dustin, so you see in the picture that you have ids with two rows (namely, ids 1, 2, 3, 5, 6). Among these, only select rows that match col1 and col2.  For the ids with only one row (ids 4 and 7), simply select those rows

Comment: What if id:5 had two combination of pizzas

Comment: Bharath, that's a good point but that never happens in my dataset.

Comment: Hi Wen, Thank you for your reply. I don't really understand how you can combine col1 and col2

Comment: Sorry misunderstand what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are only unique and duplicated values with length 2 in `id` column.

Then use [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for select all duplicates with `~` for inverse mask - select all unique rows:

```
m1 = df['Col1'] == df['Col2']
m2 = df['id'].duplicated(keep=False)
df = df[(m1 & m2) | ~m2]
print (df)
     Col1   Col2  Col3 id
0   Pizza  Pizza   100  1
3   Pizza  Pizza   300  2
4   Ramen  Ramen   230  3
6   Ramen  Pizza    13  4
8   Pizza  Pizza    13  5
10  Ramen  Ramen    30  6
11  Pizza  Ramen    45  7
```

Comment: Glad can help! One question - I use `duplicated(keep=False)` for selecting all duplicates in `id`. There is possible 3 or more dupes like id=1,1,1 ?